# Objective C: How do i find out if a number is divisible by another number?

Tags: objective-c, macos

In objective c (Mac development). How can i find out if a number is divisible by another number and not a decimal?

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you're dealing with integers, use the modulus function:

```
if ((a % b) == 0) {
  // A is divisible by B
} else {
  // A isn't divisible by B
}
```

Comment: Not working, i've tried if ((1 % 2) == 0) {
  NSLog(@"1 is divisible by 2");
 } else {
  NSLog(@"1 is NOT divisible by 2");
 }

Comment: @Daniel: And what does that result give you? Divisible or NOT Divisible?

Comment: Also how would i generate a random number that IS divisible by a certain number?

Comment: By generating a random number and multiplying it by the number you wish the final result to be divisible by?

Comment: Right, and 1 isn't divisible by 2 (you can't fit 2 into 1 an exact number of times, you can only fit it in half a time). On the other hand, 2 *is* divisible by 1

Comment: @Robin Day: I'm not sure if that's sarcasm, but I'll assume not and just go with thanks! =D

Comment: Expand the if statement to 
if ((a > b) && ((a % b) ==0)) will catch if numbers like 1 divided by 2.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a objective c programmer, but in general, just checking if A mod B = 0 should do it... won't it work in OC?

cheers.