# Alternating between two different types of UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Scenario = I have a single tableView that will be loaded up by a single array of data (coming from internet, so I can't "hardcode" this). There will be two different tableView cells and I would like to alternate between the two types one right after the other. "CELL A" will have text on the right side and a picture on the left, and "CELL B" will have text on the left side and a picture on the right. Below I sort of illustrate the desired result (not meant to be "code" just to illustrate the alternation from cell to cell in the tableView).

```
tableView =
[0]indexPath.row = "CELL A"
[1]indexPath.row = "CELL B"
[2]indexPath.row = "CELL A"
[3]indexPath.row = "CELL B"
[4]indexPath.row = "CELL A"
[5]indexPath.row = "CELL B"
```

Problem = I am not sure how to dequeueForReuseIdentifier for two different types of cells.

Request = Can anyone help me with this code, or at least point me in the right direction, or is this even possible?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am. Does it have something to do with storyboardID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, you should have a tableview with two prototype cells (one for cell A and another one for cell B). Set Identifiers for each cell (let say `cellAIdentifier` and `cellBIdentifier`).

You must also create subclasses of UITableViewCell for CellA and CellB. Then create the user interface in the prototype cell, and connect IBOutlets to the subclasses of UITableViewcell. Let say you use an IBOutlet called `label`, and another one called `imageView`.

After that, you can use rmaddy answer:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellAIdentifier"];
    } else {
        cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellBIdentifier"];
    }
    label.text = @"your text, which should be taken from your model".
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
    return cell;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is simple actually.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        // setup and return table cell type A
    } else {
        // setup and return table cell type B
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the modulus ("%") is doing?

Comment: That's a standard way to check if a value is even. If a number % 2 has a zero result, then it is an even number.

Comment: More info on %: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467728/objective-c-how-do-i-find-out-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number